# wanting to connect new m audio keyboard via usb and midi to use Finale and Sonar

Tags: midi

So both programms work via usb, but sometimes I need both programs open at once (one is music writing software, the other recording as you know). In this case I get the message that the port is in use by another program so whichever I open second won't work

Comment: You should probably add the specific model of the keyboard, and your operating system.

Comment: Operating system Windows 10 64 bit Keyboard M audio keystation 61 mark 3

Comment: Have been advised that I can only have one program open if using midi via usb….are there virtual or hardware USB hubs? Secondly I do have 5 pin midi out on the keyboard that I could put through my midisport but just won't work!

Comment: I don't think that's a general rule. When I play my MIDI controller keyboard, both Reaktor and Reason receive the notes I'm playing. Could be down to the USB drivers (my keyboard is a Novation) or the OS (I'm on Windows 7).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's interesting and hopeful that yours works OK. It was M audio that told me that I couldn't use both programs at once, and when I try it says unable to open as port is in use.